# Aggregate query with no $match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I have a collection in which unique documents from a different collection can appear over and over again (in example below `item`), depending on how much a user shares them. I want to create an aggregate query which finds the most shared documents. There is no $match necessary because I'm not matching a certain criteria, I'm just querying the most shared. Right now I have:

```
db.stories.aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            _id:'item.id', 
            'item': { 
                $first: '$item'
            }, 
            'total': { 
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
);
```

However this only returns 1 result. It occurs to me I might just need to do a simple `find` query, but I want the results aggregated, so that each result has the item and total is how many times it's appeared in the collection.

Example of a document in the stories collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    user: {
        id: ObjectId('...'),
        propertyA: ...,
        propertyB: ...,
        etc
    },
    item: {
        id: ObjectId('...'),
        propertyA: ...,
        propertyB: ...,
        etc
    }
}
```

`users` and `items` each have their own collections as well.

Comment: could you add example input document?

Comment: Ok, added an example document from stories collection.

Comment: You need to prefix `item.id` with `$`. Change `_id` in the `$group` stage to `_id:'$item.id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
_id:'item.id'
```

to

```
_id:'$item.id'
```

Currently you group by the constant 'item.id' and therefore you only get one document as result.